# outlook 2013 not porting up copied imap folders

Tags: email, imap, microsoft-outlook-2013

I recently moved to a new email host and I was moving the folders by right clicking the folder and selecting the new account and copy, from my old host to the new host. I should have copied them but I didn't think about it.

Of course Outlook froze up and I had to kill Outlook. Now I have folders in the new account on my computer that are not up on the host. It is not copying them up to the host either.

I tried this from a website I found:

```
1. In the left nav folder list, click on "[Gmail]"
2. Right click on [Gmail] .. IMAP folders
3. Query for folders containing "All"
4. Subscribe to "[Gmail]/All Mail"
4a. Tick the box "When displaying hierarchy in Outlook, show only subscribed folders"
5. Restart Outlook 2013
```

The folders in question were not listed, even when I unchecked the above option. As you can see below, there are only a few folders. There are many more that I need.

[image]

Can I force Outlook to upload these folder. Any suggestions on how to salvage these folders? Like I said, I moved them to the new host, not copied. I'm not even sure which emails made it up yet.

I don't see any errors while syncing and I have turned on the advanced logging but I see no log files being generated. I really would not like to loose these emails.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

I need to add that I ran:

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\SCANPST.EXE"

And it found minor errors. I fixed them then started the program without any luck.

Comment: PST doesn't help with IMAP accounts

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not sure what that means...? They were all IMAP accounts.

Comment: Yes; so repair your PST file didn't do much

Comment: @Ramhound I repaired the OST file not a pst file.

Comment: I just talked to Microsoft Support, they said to re-install windows.  :-)

Comment: @Timbo Get right on that... I'll update you on my progress once I am done ;-D